# how to doing sum of column .Sum of row takes place

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="MainTimeSheetDetails">
 <input type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-danger"value="Delete">
<input type="button"  style="float:right" class="btn btn-warning" value="Recall">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float:right" value="Submit">

<input  onclick="btnsave()" type="button" class="btn btn-success"  style="float:right" value="Save">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">Project</th>
        <th width="30%">Tasks <input onclick="LoadPreviousWeek()" type="button" id="btnNext"  style="width:20px;float:right" value="<" /> </th>

        @{DateTime Date = ViewBag.StartDate;}
        @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            <th>@Html.Raw(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("ddd  dd"))</th>

        }
        <td class="success"><input onclick="LoadNextWeek()" type="button" style="width:20px;float:left" value=">" />Total</td>

    </tr>

    @{
        List<TSM.Models.Tasks> lstTasks = ViewBag.Tasks;
    }
    @foreach (TSM.Models.Projects.Project item in ViewBag.Project)
    {
        <tr>

        <td colspan="10"  style="background-color:antiquewhite;">@item.ProjectName </td>
    </tr>

        foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
        {
            <tr id="tmsData">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@itm.TaskName</td>

                @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)

                  {

                    <td > <input class="txtTaskHours date@(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyyy"))" style="width:50px;"   type="number" id="@(itm.ID.ToString() + ':' + Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyyy"))" /></td>
                }
                <td><strong><input class="JKL" style="width:50px" /></strong></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>


               </tr>
        }

    }

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {

                <td ><strong><input class="JKLL " id="Tue" style="width:50px" /></strong></td>

            }
            <td></td>


        </tr>

</table>
```

```
   <script> 

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $(".txtTaskHours").on('keyup change', calculateSum);
                    });

                    function calculateSum() {
                        var $input = $(this);
                        var $row = $input.closest('tr');
                        var sum = 0;

                        $row.find(".txtTaskHours").each(function () {
                            sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
                        });

                        $row.find(".JKL").val(sum.toFixed(2));
 </script>
```

This is my script method.sum of row is done but how to do sum of column.For the row i used this script method and sum of row take place very well but how to use this script method for sum of column of multiple column like this row method.All the sum of different row is show in the different text box..Then how to show every column sum is show in different textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your data rows to have `class="tmsData"`, not `id="tmsData"`

```
<tr class="tmsData">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</tr>
```

Then ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".txtTaskHours").on('keyup change', function() {
        var $rows = $(this).closest('table').find('tr.tmsData'); // select all qualifying rows
        var columnTotals = [];
        $rows.each(function(i, row) {
            var $row = $(row);
            var rowTotal = $row.find(".txtTaskHours").get().reduce(function(runningRowTotal, hoursInput, j) { // use Array#reduce() to calculate row total
                var val = parseFloat(hoursInput.value) || 0;
                columnTotals[j] = (columnTotals[j] || 0) + val; // accumuulate column totlas during the rowTotal reduction
                return runningRowTotal + val;
            }, 0);
            $row.find(".JKL").val(rowTotal.toFixed(2));
        });
        $("input.JKLL").each(function(i) { // select all column total elements
            this.value = columnTotals[i];
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In my code Where i give <tbody> syntax. i mean where <tbody> syntax is start t.

Comment: This error is  getting ..//////Reduce of empty array with no initial value. .Tell me in my code where i give the <tbody>

Comment: My mistake ... fixed.

Comment: `<tbody> @foreach (TSM.Models.Projects.Project item in ViewBag.Project) { ... } </tbody>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my `<tbody>`  idea will work. The data rows appear to come in sets of three. See amended answer.

Comment: Sorry, I my `<tbody>` idea won't work. The data rows appear to come in sets of three. See amended answer.

Comment: Row function is work properly but i getting this error //this.val is not a function..//. the column function is not working

Comment: Amended - try again.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer .Its Working